# /tf topic is not published with specified namespace

Tags: ros-humble, turtlebot3, robot-state-publisher

I am working on a project involving multiple TurtleBots, using Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 Humble. I would like to control them individually by running a separate navigation stack (with unique namespace) for each robot. I have been able to set up individual stacks for Gazebo-simulated bots, but when trying to run the stack on physical robots (following the guide [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/giving-a-turtlebot3-a-namespace-for-multi-robot-experiments/10756)), I cannot get /tf and /tf_static to conform to the specified namespaces. All other topics publish as expected:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout
/tb3_0/battery_state
...
/tb3_0/scan
/tb3_0/sensor_state
/tf
/tf_static
```

I suspect it is an issue with the robot_state_publisher node, which is launched in the tb3_0 namespace, but still publishes to /tf and /tf_static.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ros2 node info /tb3_0/robot_state_publisher
/tb3_0/robot_state_publisher
  Subscribers:
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /tb3_0/joint_states: sensor_msgs/msg/JointState
  Publishers:
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
    /tb3_0/robot_description: std_msgs/msg/String
    /tf: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
    /tf_static: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
  Service Servers: 
  ...
```

What might be the reason for this, and how could I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to address the problem through remapping the topic names when the offending nodes are initialized. robot_state_publisher itself publishes to /tf and /tf_static, and diff_drive_controller (initialized by turtlebot3_node) publishes to /tf. To allow the namespace to be prefixed on those channels, I had to remap '/tf' to 'tf' and '/tf_static' to 'tf_static'.

Where robot_state_publisher is initialized (turtlebot3_state_publisher.launch.py in the base bringup package):

```
Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            namespace='tb3_0',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[rsp_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
            remappings=[('/tf','tf'),('/tf_static','tf_static')]
            )
```

And where turtlebot3_node is initialized (robot.launch.py in the base bringup package):

```
Node(
            package='turtlebot3_node',
            executable='turtlebot3_ros',
            namespace='tb3_0',  # <------------------- ADD THIS!
            parameters=[tb3_param_dir],
            arguments=['-i', usb_port],
            remappings=[('/tf','tf'),('/tf_static','tf_static')],
            output='screen'
            )
```

And voila!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout
/tb3_0/battery_state
...
/tb3_0/sensor_state
/tb3_0/tf
/tb3_0/tf_static
```

It'd be nice to be able to set this as an automated launch argument, rather than having to manually configure every bot. But for now, this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the exact same issue (on Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS2-foxy) and i also tried the solution same solution that you did but it did not work.

But in the meantime if you want to try things with simulation you can try [this](https://github.com/francocipollone/multi_turtlebot_sim) repo. It works perfectly and namespaces tf tree, nodes and topics.

If you find a solution do update here.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem through remapping; see the update post!

Comment: Thanks a lot  : ), it worked..

Comment: @firthc But after doing this when i tried to get tf tree using `ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames.py`, the downloaded pdf file says "No tf data recieved". So i remapped `/tf` to `/tb3_0/tf` and used the command: `ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames.py --ros-args --remap /tf:=/tb3_0/tf`. Now, tf data is recived but tf tree is broken to two parts (odom and basefootprint ) and second part contains rest of the tree and also the base scan is missing.